# Is it a good practice to have the public key in javascript?

Tags: key, public

I am trying to implement google `reCAPTCHA` in my website.

The tutorial tells me to paste my public key into a javascript snippet.

Is inserting the public key safe or should I encrypt it? If yes, how?

Comment: If you encrypt it, how are you going to decrypt it before using it? Where are you going to store the key to do that decryption?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a public key, not a private key. Public keys are meant to be distributed. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key):

> The public key is widely distributed, while the private key is known only to its proprietor. The keys are related mathematically, but the parameters are chosen so that calculating the private key from the public key is either impossible or prohibitively expensive.